# Jython equivalent of Java Code

Tags: java, python, jython

I want to convert the following Java code into Jython code. I dont know much about Java.

```
String name = connection.runReadAction(new ReadActionResult<String>()
{
     public String execute(SystemAccess access) throws Exception
     {
        return access.getTree(SystemTree.Geographic).resolve(path).getDisplayName();
     }
 });
```

Can you please help me do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def execute(access):
  return access.getTree(SystemTree.Geographic).resolve(path).getDisplayName()

name = connection.runReadAction(readActionResult=execute)
```

Jython handles the messy details of creating anonymous inner classes.